# Mathematical trivia (i.e. collections of anecdotes and miscellaneous (recreational) mathematics)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, book-recommendation

Can you suggest some books on mathematical trivia?

I use the word "trivia" with a double meaning in this case:

- curious anecdotes that enlighten what the real life of mathematicians is like (like the ones in *Mathematical Apocrypha Redux*);
- curious miscellaneous (also mainly recreational) mathematical ideas and topics with only occasional anecdotes and jokes (like the ones in *Professor Stewart's Cabinet of Mathematical Curiosities* and *Professor Stewart's Hoard of Mathematical Tresures*).

Comment: You can't go far wrong with the work of [Simon Singh](http://simonsingh.net/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestions:

1.["The Penguin book of curious and interesting mathematics"](http://books.google.it/books/about/The_Penguin_book_of_curious_and_interest.html?id=fG9GAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y) by David G. Wells;

2.["The Colossal Book of Mathematics"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/415052.The_Colossal_Book_of_Mathematics) by Martin Gardner;

3.["Maths Facts, Fun, Tricks and Trivia"](http://www.ricgroup.com.au/product/maths-facts-tricks-and-trivia/) by Paul Swan;

4.["Math hysteria"](http://m.barnesandnoble.com/w/math-hysteria-ian-stewart/1006180647?ean=9780198613367) by Ian Stewart;

5.["In Mathematical Circles: A Selection of Mathematical Stories and Anecdotes: Quadrants I, II, III, and IV (Mathematical Association of America)"](http://www.abebooks.com/9780883855423/Mathematical-Circles-Selection-Stories-Anecdotes-0883855429/plp) by Howard W. Eves.

Answer (score 4):

$The$ $Math$ B$ook$ is a personal favorite of mine.

Comment: Good. I like it too. Thanks for your contribution to this list.

Answer (score 3):

The book *Mathematical People: Profiles and Interviews* has some nice anecdotes.

Comment: Great book. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Automathography' of Paul R. Halmos, I WANT TO BE A MATHEMATICIAN might be of some interest to you.

Comment: I like this book a lot. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

The biography of Paul Erdős, *The Man Who Loved Only Numbers* written by Paul Hoffman, may be of some interest to you as it certainly does contain mathematical ideas as well as interesting stories about a rather eccentric mathematician.

Comment: I love that book (and that man)! :)

Answer (score 2):

Some Polish accents...

1. Stanisław M. Ulam, *Adventures of a Mathematician*
2. The Scottish Book: Mathematics from the Scottish Café, ed. D. Mauldin, Birkäuser, Boston-Basel-Stuttgart, 1981.
3. Roman Kałuża, Through a reporter's eyes: The life of Stefan Banach, Birkäuser, Boston-Bazylea-Berlin, 1996, 2005.
4. Kazimierz Kuratowski: A Half Century of Polish Mathematics: Remembrances and Reflections, Pergamon Press, Oxford and PWN, Warszawa, 1980. (With a famous photograph, where after enumerating many professor there is  "and Czesław Ryll-Nardzewski, at that time second year student of mathematics" [cited from memory]).
5. Krzysztof Ciesielski, Zdzisław Pogoda, *Diamenty matematyki* (*Diamonds of Mathematics*, in Polish. I am afraid not translated into English, but some fragments are obtainable in the WEB.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your suggestions :).