# math-biography of mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, math-history, mathematicians

Some of the mathematicians agree that reading biography (or more specifically, math-autobiography, scientific-biography) gives lot of inspiration for working; and I am one of them.

One book which I know is: [An Automathography by Paul Halmos](http://www.amazon.in/Want-Mathematician-An-Automathography/dp/0387960783).

My request is: Can you recommend few more similar types, that is, auomathography, or biography of mathematicians ?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not recommending this, I've never read it, but Russell has [written an autobiography](http://www.amazon.com/Autobiography-Routledge-Classics-Bertrand-Russell/dp/041547373X).

Comment: Do you mean "intellectual biographies" (i.e., biographies that mostly discuss a mathematician's mathematical achievements)? If so, Judith Grabiner's [_The Origins of Cauchy's Rigorous Calculus_](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/867773939) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Men of Mathematics By Eric Temple Bell

Man who knew Infinity By Robert Kanigel

Both are my best of best books .You must read them

Answer (score 3):

I hope this link will help you:
http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/24303.Mathematical_Biography#714583

You might as well have a look at:

[Mathematical trivia (i.e. collections of anecdotes and miscellaneous (recreational) mathematics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002768/mathematical-trivia-i-e-collections-of-anecdotes-and-miscellaneous-recreation/1016500#1016500)

Answer (score 2):

Ulam's book of course : ["Adventures of a Mathematician"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0520071549).

Answer (score 2):

Marc Kac's [Enigmas of Chance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0520059867).

Answer (score 1):

My personal Favourite are:

$1$.  A beautiful mind by sylvia nasar

$2$.  Euler:Master of us all by William Dunham (It is full of mathematical knowledge and exitement).

Answer (score 0):

cpl here:

1. Definitely echo Eric Temple Bell's *Men of Mathematics* for a more encyclopaedic volume
2. *The Man Who Loved Only Numbers*: Paul Hoffman's biography of Paul Erdos - a real delight to read, what comes through is a wonderful and inspiring description of a truly wonderful, humorous, kind and obviously gifted human being :)