# Are there any books out there that talk about the lives of mathematicians?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question

I recently read lots about the discovery of calculus of variations. The maths of this period is outstanding, however *almost* from what I can gather was the lives of Newton, Leibniz, the Bernoullis etc and how these problems were discussed. However I can only find scraps and it's almost as if its thrown in and the authoer is embarrassed to do.

I guess I am looking for something similar to that you would find of the lives of Shelly, Byron, Coleridge. However rather than romantic poetry, I would like something similar on the mathematicains during the discovry of calculus of variations. Maybe I am failing with my keywords and/or the stores in which I am looking, however so far I have drawn a blank.

Comment: One of my professors recommended "Men of Mathematics" to me a while back; it is more of an anthology of these biographies I believe. One biography that I have REALLY enjoyed is "The Man Who Loved Only Numbers" by Paul Hoffman; it is all about Paul Erdos, a truly amazing mathematician of recent history

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022796/math-biography-of-mathematicians

Comment: What are you looking for? Books about the lives of mathematicians, or books specifically about the lives of the mathematicians involved in the early history of the calculus of variations?

Comment: Those involved in calculus & calculus of variations. The rivalry between Newton/Leibniz, the bernoulli brothers and the mentorship/friendship between Euler and Lagrange.

Comment: This might be better asked at https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: For a more complete perspective on the history of calculus of variations (that does more than just focus on the 10-20 most important individuals involved), I recommend [**A History of the Calculus of Variations from the 17th through the 19th Century**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387905219) by Herman H. Goldstine (1980) and [**A History of the Progress of the Calculus of Variations during the Nineteenth Century**](https://archive.org/details/historyofprogres00todhuoft) by Isaac Todhunter (1861).

Answer (score 2):

*Men of Mathematics* by E. T. Bell, as mentioned by ThomasGrubb, is appropriate for reading about mathematicians up to the 19th century.  In particular: Newton, Leibniz, Bernoulli, Bernoulli. Great for learning about them, if you know next to nothing about them.  (But more sophisticated readers should note that Bell romanticized some of the stories.)

In some cases there are book-length scholarly biographies that you can find if you want more, after the introduction in Bell.  In particular, of course, Newton and Leibniz have many such biographies.

Answer (score 0):

For romanticized biographies of mathematicians, Constance Reid is pretty good, and in my opinion less inaccurate than E.T.Bell (who is notoriously inaccurate) mentioned in the other answer.  I enjoyed her account of Hilbert's preparations for his famous 1900 talk in Paris.  See [her books here](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387962566).